# ¿Cómo habilitar y desabilitar botones según la pestaña de un TabControl en C#?

Tags: c#, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo Un TabControl en C# que tiene dos pestañas, cada uno con un DataGridView. A su lado están 3 botones: Bloquear, Desbloquear y Refrescar.
Quiero que al seleccionar la pestaña uno, el botón desbloquear quede des-habilitado y los otros dos habilitados. Mientras que al presionar la pestaña dos, sea lo contrario: Botón Bloquear des-habilitado y los otros dos habilitados. Esto en C#.
[image: Adjunto captura del diseño del formulario para mejor entendimiento]

Answer (score 1):

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var blnResp = true;

        //Comparas la propiedad del nombre del TabPage que has agregado.
        blnResp = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name == "tabUno";

        //Llamas a un funcion que te habilita o deshabilita los botones.
        FnEsadoBotones(blnResp);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}

private void FnEsadoBotones(bool estado)
{
    button1.Enabled = estado;
    button2.Enabled = estado;
    button3.Enabled = !estado;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué función tiene el catch en este caso? ¿Es omitible, se puede dejar vacío?